# How to get unlimited multiple options from typer.Option with custom devider

Tags: python, command-line-interface, typer

I want to divide unlimited values with a custom divider in `typer.Option`. below is an example of what I need:

```bash
$ python main.py add -C "first one","second one","third"
```

and output should be:

```py
["first one","second one","third"]
```

is there any way to do this with typer and python?

Answer (score 0):

to have an option with unlimited values, you can get a string and split it by a separator and get a list.

You can try this:

```
import typer


app = typer.Typer()


@app.callback()
def main():
    pass


@app.command()
def add(elements: str = typer.Option(..., help="List of elements separated by a comma")):
        
    elements_splited = [element.strip() for element in elements.split(",")]
    typer.echo(elements_splited)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

So :

> python main.py add --elements "el1, el2, el3, el4"

You will get:

> ['el1', 'el2', 'el3', 'el4']

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want to separate something like `"first one","second one"` your solution works for just one syllable items. But i want to sperate two or more syllable items like "first item".

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters and use less blank lines in your code.

Comment: With Typer the options take a single value by default. Giving values separated by commas would be problematic because Typer will consider the extra values as other commands.

If you want to pass values like this and get a list back, you will have to specify the option each time:

`python main.py add -c "el1" -c "el2"`

Comment: @buhtz I didn't get what you are talking about.

Comment: @almamy-code I have this solution in my code, but I want to change it as I described. As you said, my problem is Typer considers the extra values as other commands.